# Vertx in Mac OS is throwing "Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider"

Tags: java-11, vert.x

I'm getting below error when running a simple vertx program in macos os. After few investigation in google/stackoverflow,  the respective jar is also added in pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.76.Final</version>
      <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But still the issues is not getting solved. I am using Java 11. How to solve this kind of issue?

> Oct 06, 2023 8:25:05 AM io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders <clinit>
> SEVERE: Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider, fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS. Check whether you have a dependency on 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos'. Use DEBUG level to see the full stack: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library